# How do add items from a list in an iterative fashion to two different lists?

Tags: python

I have a time-series consisting of numeric data points, say in form of a list:

```py
x = [924, -5, 24, 1, 0, 242, -5, 42, 5, 1, -9, 50, 3, 432, 0, -5, 4]
```

I need to populate these two lists:

```py
x_list = []
y_list = []
```

following these three steps:

1. The first two values from the list, `x[0]` and `x[1]`, namely 924 and -5, should be added to these two lists below, respectively.
2. The second aim is to take the next two values or "pairs" of the list, namely `x[1]` and `x[2]`, and add them to `x_list` and `y_list`, respectively.
3. Finally, I would like to repeat this step, i.e., adding `x[2]` to `x_list` and `x[3]` to `y_list` and so on, until the end of the time-series `x` is reached.

I assume that I have to program a function using `def`. But I don't understand how to set up the code for this aim. Here is the current state of my code.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot. as plt

x = [924, -5, 24, 1, 0, 242, -5, 42, 5, 1, -9, 50, 3, 432, 0, -5, 4]

x_results = []
y_results = []

for t in Timeseries:
next_n = # This is where I am stuck, struggling to find the correct code
next_y = 
x_results.append(next_x)
y_results.append(next_y)

plt.plot(x_results, y_results, "bo")
plt.show()
```

Comment: What's the expected output for the final lists?

Comment: so x[1]~x[-1] would appear twice?

Comment: Shouldn't `x(1)` be `x[0]`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. In the python language I indeed meant x[0] instead of x(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for python ≥ 3.10, this is the job of [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise):

```
from itertools import pairwise
x, y = zip(*pairwise(mylist))
```

output:

```
x
(924, -5, 24, 1, 0, 242, -5, 42, 5, 1, -9, 50, 3, 432, 0, -5),

y
(-5, 24, 1, 0, 242, -5, 42, 5, 1, -9, 50, 3, 432, 0, -5, 4)
```

for python < 3.10, the recipe for pairwise is:

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

Comment: @Philipp: It is cool that you got another working answer to your question, but I wonder if you realize you can only select one answer as the "best" answer, and this is the much less efficient and clear method for getting the result. You can see the time difference in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/theherk/27434de0502e874497176dcf299bf76e).

Answer (score 3):

You can use two slices:

```py
mylist = [924, -5, 24, 1, 0, 242, -5, 42, 5, 1, -9, 50, 3, 432, 0, -5, 4]

x_list = mylist[:-1]
y_list = mylist[1:]
```

Comment: This is a great answer. No comprehension or looping required.

Comment: And if it does turn out that they really did want pairs of evens and odds, though this seems to be what was asked for, it would still be similarly simply. Just `x_list = mylist[::2]` and `y_list = mylist[1::2]`.